# Trying to deploy Angular 8 app to Heroku - build successful but heroku saying 'Not Found'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, heroku, angular8

I am trying to deploy my angular app to heroku, the builds are successful but when i go to my link, it is telling me 'Not Found'. I am really confused as to what is going on because I have visited various websites which go through the steps and I am sure that I am following the steps properly. 
I have a procfile which has 
web: node server.js

My package.json looks like this -

```
{
  "name": "ng-barry-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --aot --prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.17",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.13",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.5.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.25",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.11.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.802.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.17",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.13",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.9.1",
    "npm": "6.10.2"
  }
}
```

This is my server.js file

```
//Install express server
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// Serve only the static files form the dist directory
app.use(express.static('./dist/pi-project'));

app.get('/*', function(req,res) {

res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/dist/pi-project/index.html'));
});

// Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Comment: could you solve it, because i have the same problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this .[click here](https://github.com/souravgolui/matDash/blob/master/server.js)

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems correct, just cross check the following points if it may help

1. You might get error running the postinstall command. This works instead:

`heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod`

1. Node and npm engine should be same version you have on your machine. So, run `node -v` and `npm -v` to get the correct version and include it in your package.json

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! I have just tried that but it is still not working. Even did it with a completely new Heroku app and deleted the old one... :(

Comment: Can you check the logs using heroku cli

````heroku logs --tail````

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me for angular 6 and angular 7 deployment on heroku. 
Try this- `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hE1i_LhL_Nc`

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

You need a couple of Edits to your server.js file

Change this:

`app.use(express.static('./dist/pi-project'));`

To This:

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'./dist/pi-project')));`

And Change this:

`app.get('/*', function(req,res) {`

To this

`app.get('/', function(req,res) {`

so that not all requests are serviced by this function

**Original Answer**

In your server.js you have the following:

```
app.get('/*', function(req,res) {

res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/dist/pi-project/index.html'));
});
```

Because of the asterisk after the /, that's saying to return the index.html file for every request that comes in.  So what will happen is that you'll first make a request to localhost:8080 and that will return the index.html (so far so good).  Then the browser will read the `<script>` tags from the index.html and for each one it will make another request.  So let's say the next request will be to localhost:8080/main.js.  When express sees that it will AGAIN return index.html which obviously isn't what you want.

To fix that problem you can change your server.js to this:

```
//Install express server
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// Serve only the static files form the dist directory
app.use(express.static('./dist/pi-project'));

app.get('/*', function(req,res) {

  if(req.url === '/') {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/dist/pi-project/index.html'));
  }
  else {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/pi-project' + req.url))
  }

});

// Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```